# Github Actions db service container not reachable

Tags: docker, github, elixir, github-actions

I have the following Github Actions pipeline:

```
name: Elixir CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'

  pull_request:
    branches:
        - '*'

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Docker Setup Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1.6.0
      with:
        install: true
    - name: building image
      env:
        DATABASE_HOST: postgres
        DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      run: |
        docker build --build-arg DATABASE_HOST=$DATABASE_HOST -t backend:test -f Dockerfile.ci .
```

I have a single build step for an Elixir app: the dockerfile is a multistage one, the first stage runs the tests and builds the production app, and the second copies the application folder/tar.

`DATABASE_HOST` is the variable that my Elixir app looks for to connect to the test environment.

I have the need to run tests against Postgres, so I spawn a container service with it. I have executed the build both in a container and outside of it, but I always have the following error:

```
...

#19 195.9 14:10:58.624 [error] GenServer #PID<0.9316.0> terminating
#19 195.9 ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (postgres:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
#19 195.9     (db_connection 2.4.1) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
#19 195.9     (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
#19 195.9     (stdlib 3.14.2.2) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
#19 195.9 Last message: nil
...
```

So apparently `postgres:5432` is not reachable, am I missing something ?

Comment: Longshot: does it work if you change `DATABASE_HOST` to `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `DATABASE_HOST: postgres` I think.

The service container exports `5432` port to host, so for docker build, it should use `host's ip address` to visit that `postgres service` like next:

```
- name: building image
  env:
    DATABASE_PORT: 5432
  run: |
    DATABASE_HOST=$(ifconfig -a eth0|grep inet|grep -v 127.0.0.1|grep -v inet6|awk '{print $2}'|tr -d "addr:")
    docker build --build-arg DATABASE_HOST=$DATABASE_HOST -t backend:test -f Dockerfile.ci .
```

Above will first use `ifconfig` to get virtual machine's ip(docker host's ip), then pass to docker build to let build container to visit the postgres.